# Get reference variable outside of component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, angular8

I have this code in order to toggle a drawer / matsidebar.

**app-component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<mat-toolbar color="accent">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <button mat-button (click)="leftbar.toggle()" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="ng-container centered">
  <mat-sidenav #leftbar opened mode="side">
    <app-leftnav></app-leftnav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

If I click on the menu icon, the left side bar is toggled opened / closed. There is no typescript or extra service. It works out of the box. However, I need to put my mat-toolbar in the actual app-header component. So instead I do something like this:

**app-component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<mat-sidenav-container class="ng-container centered">
  <mat-sidenav #leftbar opened mode="side">
    <app-leftnav></app-leftnav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**header-component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="accent">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <button mat-button (click)="leftbar.toggle()" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This does not work because the #leftbar is not known to the header component as expected. How do I do this? I keep seeing examples using something like this:

```
@ViewChild('leftbar') sidebar: ElementRef;
```

I keep researching this question, and getting old answers from Angular 2 when the template was in the ts component file. Also, generally, the component with the drawer in it (or whatever function) is inside the header not the other way around. Is it completely necessary to create a service for this? If so, how? What is the simplest, correct, and least amount of typescript way to do this in Angular 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be emitting Output event from your header component:

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Output() menuButtonClicked = new EventEmitter();
  ...
```

**header.component.html**

```
<button mat-button (click)="menuButtonClicked.emit()"
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header (menuButtonClicked)="leftbar.toggle()"></app-header>
<mat-sidenav-container class="ng-container centered">
  <mat-sidenav #leftbar opened mode="side">
    Side bar
  </mat-sidenav>
  ...
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5jfc2?file=app/header/header.component.ts)**

Comment: This worked great.  I had to import Output and EventEmitter as well.  Could I have used the @ViewChild component?

Comment: Yes, you can use it

Comment: How? While your answer is the easiest, I toggled for 2 days trying to figure out the View Child component.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5jfc2-qpsb6n?file=app%2Fmenu-overview-example.html

Comment: 2 great ways to do exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you for taking the time!